# How to click radiobutton which doesnt have any changes in the DOM except some tags like "::before ==" in protractor

Tags: protractor, radio-button

I am trying to click radiobutton, the related tag for this looks something like "::before==$0" in DOM. How to select this? I thought "input" is the tag for radiobutton, but on hover got "::before==$0" as the related hover, developer says its CSS tag.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: it seems thats what the element looks when it's selected, how does it look when its unselected? or is it the same

Comment: You can't select  **pseudo-element** from web page by css selector or xpath. In you r case, I think click on the text `4 July 2019` following the radio button will check the radio button.

Comment: hi @Jackey why do you not choose div.row.label-data to click ?

Comment: Exactly,  div.row.label-data is the element was suppose to be used instead of ::before or input tag. Devtools never highlighted  div.row.label-data as the corresponding element bt it had worked when i interacted with  div.row.label-data for radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes AquariusPotter, div.row.label-data is the element was suppose to be used instead of ::before or input tag. Devtools never highlighted div.row.label-data as the corresponding element bt it had worked when i interacted with div.row.label-data for radio button.

I tried this and it worked!!Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try the below locator

```
const radioButton = element.all(by.css('fs-18-light.mc-od');

await radioButton.get(0).click(); // TO select 4 Jul 2019
```

Increase the `index` based on the radio button you want to click

Hope it helps you